# the apache configuration file httpd.conf couldn't be written in MAMP PRO 4 OSX

Tags: apache, mamp-pro

I have just installed and registered MAMP PRO 4 in OSX but when I Try to star server I get this error: the apache configuration file httpd.conf couldn't be written in MAMP PRO 4

Any idea please?
Regards

Comment: Well, make that file writable for the process?

Comment: the httpd.conf file has read/write permissions to my user and the admin user. I must give permissions to the particular process of mamp pro?

Answer (score 2):

Reboot your mac. Usually that does it!

Answer (score 1):

I just upgraded to MAMP Pro 4.1 and I had the same exact error.  I right-clicked on the httpd.conf file, selected "Get Info", down in "Sharing & Permissions" I changed them all to "Read & Write".  I then did the exact same thing to the "Apache" folder itself that the httpd.conf file is in.  Then back in MAMP I stopped the server, then restarted it and it worked.  So honestly I don't know if it was the permission changes I did, or if it was just the restart of the server, or both.  But it worked for me.  After the server was able to start I changed my permissions back to how they initially were for the httpd.conf file and the Apache directory, starting and stopping the server still works.

Answer (score 1):

For me, stopping servers, starting system websharing (`Tools->Start system Apache`) and then stopping it, and then rebooting did the trick. (MAMP 4.2).

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem you need to follow these steps:

1. Uninstall v4.2 using CleanMyMac
2. Install older MAMPPRO v4.1.1
3. Uninstall v4.1.1
4. Restart your Mac
5. Install MAMPPRO v4.2 again

Done!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - read through each of the above solutions, unfortunately none of them fully worked for me, I kept getting the same error when launching MAMP Pro. Here's how I was able to resolve it:

- Fully uninstall MAMP and MAMP Pro via CleanMyMac X app
- Check for any errors in the log, and manually removed any files that
  CleanMyMac wasn't able to
- Restart computer
- Re-install MAMP

And that finally worked for me.